# If all variables are true, return true

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular component I have the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myApp',
  templateUrl: './my-app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-app.component.scss']

})
export class MyApp implements OnInit {

  accordion1: boolean;
  accordion2: boolean;
  accordion3: boolean;
  accordionAll: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleAll(): void {
    this.accordionAll1 = !this.accordionAll
    this.accordion1 = this.accordionAll;
    this.accordion2 = this.accordionAll;
    this.accordion3 = this.accordionAll;
  }
}
```

So with this I can have individual buttons that can toggle the state to true or false with e.g.:

```
<div (click)="accordion1 = !accordion1" [ngClass]="accordion1 ? 'is-active' : ''"></div>
```

or I can make all of them true or false at the same time if I click on the button that has:

```
<div (click)="toggleAll()" [ngClass]="accordionAll ? 'is-active' : ''"></div>
```

And this works as intended. However, if the starting state of `accordionAll` is false, and all the other states are individually clicked to a true state, `accordionAll` will stay false. But what I would like is for it to turn true if all of the others are individually either true or false.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info

Comment: Spelling mistake ` this.accordionAll1` in `toggleAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.accordionAll` will only true if `accordion1`, `accordion2`, and `accordion3` are true

And

`this.accordionAll` will only false if `accordion1` or `accordion2` or `accordion3` is false

In templete:

```
<div (click)="accordion1 = !accordion1; shouldToggleAll()" [ngClass]="accordion1 ? 'is-active' : ''"></div>
<div (click)="accordion2 = !accordion2; shouldToggleAll()" [ngClass]="accordion2 ? 'is-active' : ''"></div>
<div (click)="accordion3 = !accordion3; shouldToggleAll()" [ngClass]="accordion3 ? 'is-active' : ''"></div>
```

In ts file

```
  shouldToggleAll() {
    this.accordionAll = this.accordion1 && this.accordion2 && this.accordion3;
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdsdap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)